# How to kill Mothrakk from the Like A Moth To Flame mission

Tags: borderlands

Mothrakk seems really difficult to kill when playing single player. Is there an easy way to kill her?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bring a vehicle and use the mounted gun. Either will work, Rocket Launcher is easier but will take more time, Machine Gun is a bit quicker but a little bit more difficult because you actually have to aim it.

While in the gunner seat of the vehicle Mothrakk won't actually fire on you. Cheezy strat (AI Bug), but it works.

For a valid strat, run to the bottom of the hill and take cover under the roof of that building and just pop out to shoot her and pop back under while she shoots fire down. A good sniper rifle is best for this strat. It'll take a while, but you'll get it eventually.

Comment: I totally didn't know that re: vehicle AI bug. Huh. Another strategy I used was going to that land bridge (near the entrance of the Shock Cave I believe) and hiding under there while taking potshots at her. Bonus there is that there's also a respawn point right there in case you die. 

Overall, I'd say coverage from above is your most important priority, no matter where you decide to fight.

Comment: I managed to do it with the machine gun on the vehicle, thanks. I didn't know that it had a lock on feature, which was really handy. I basically lined the vehicle up and pressed X (PS3) until the target looked on. Then all I had to do was drive round and hold the fire button down.

Comment: Apparently the AI bug mentioned in this answer doesn't happen all the time... The Mothrakk definitely attacked (and killed) me while I was shooting it from the gunner seat.

Comment: +1 from me. The "valid strat" is exactly how I did it first time around. Just takes patience.

Comment: Signed in just to +1 the AI bug not always happening, killed me too :)

Answer (score 5):

One good way is to hide inside the vehicle station shown in the map (the fire balls won't hit you there):

[image: Good place to be]

You go out, shoot and go back inside the vehicle station waiting for the fire balls. And keep repeating the process.

Comment: You can also spawn a machine-gun vehicle there, drive out slightly, switch to the gunner and blast the Mothrakk a much of times, then leap out and hide in the vehicle station while the fireballs rain down. The vehicle machinegun was the best weapon (in my opinion) for this as there's no reloading needed, and infinite ammo.

Answer (score 4):

Mothrakk is weaker versus **explosive** weapons more than anything else. So get a good explosive weapon, hide in the car garage and ping away!

If you're running a Soldier having a nice Ammo Regen mod is also very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Start the mission, i.e. get Mothrakk going. Spawn a machine gun runner and go up to the bandit camp on the mountain behind where the three beacons you light for the mission are. This puts you about level with the circling Mothrakk. Line up so that you have a flat piece of ground that you can go forward and back on. Lock the turret guns on and start firing. She will come over to bombard you. Keep locked on and firing with the turret gun, and drive forward/back in a straight line about 50 metres at a time to avoid her bombardment. She may lose interest and go back to circling, in which case repeat the process.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way ever to kill the mothrakk it took me 5-7 min. Find one good hiding spot and fire away it will not attack if it can't see you. My hiding spot was the red carp a bit behind where you complete the circle of death missions. Kill all the bandits and hide under the red carp next to the red box thats there. Hope it works for y'all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the missile vehicle was the best I just park the car by that little house down the hill where the bandits are and where you get the weapons in the basement and just fired missiles away until it died for some reason it doesn't come after you in the missile vehicle it'll take a while especially if you're inaccurate at the timing like me but it eventually died